# Python: Script prints out dictionary value letter by letter instead of full word?

Tags: python, function, class, dictionary, printing

I have a class:

```
class Bike(object):
    """Parent class for bikes"""

    def __init__(self, name, weight, cost):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
        self.cost = cost

    def model(self):
        for trait in self.name:
            print trait

    def pounds(self):
        for trait in self.weight:
            print trait

    def money(self):
        for trait in self.cost:
            print trait
```

I created a dictionary with several key/value associations:

```
bikes = {}

# Bike designed for children"
bikes['bike1'] = Bike("Trike", "20", "100")
```

6 bikes like above,

and when I try to run them:

```
bikes['bike1'].model()
bikes['bike1'].pounds()
bikes['bike1'].money()
```

I do in fact get a print of the name, weight, and cost,

but it prints out letter by letter:

T

r

i

k

e

2

0

1

0

0

What am I missing?

Comment: because of my for statement?

    for trait in self.weight 

is this assigning each letter to "trait" as independent values?

Comment: Try `print self.name` instead of `for trait in self.name: print trait`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These lines:

```
        for trait in self.name:
            print trait
```

self.name is a string.  If you loop over a string, you get the individual characters one by one.  Your print statement thus prints each character, one-by-one.  If you want to print the name of the model, just:

```
print self.name
```

You don't need a loop here at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
for trait in self.name:
        print trait
```

handles `trait` as every character in the string `self.name` and the loop-body gets executed for every charecter in the string. So every character gets printed on a seperate line. What you want to use to print out the name in one word and one line is this. The same goes for your other methods and attributes:

```
def model(self):
    print self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because type of self.name, self.cost is string.
You won't face that issue if you will wrap that values to list
for exmple

> Bike(["Trike"], ["20"], ["100"])

Other option is simply print them in .model(), .pounds(), .money() without 
for loop